# JS variable not working inside Ionic

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am trying to manipulate a div using simple JavaScript function. But it is giving error on the variable used:

> originalText is not defined

**home.ts** code:

```
declare var orginalText: any;

imports ...

export class HomePage{
constructor(){...}

ngOnInit () {

      $('#changeText').click(function(){
         orginalText = $('#content').html();
        $('#content').text("This is text changed using jquery");
      });

      $('#changeText2').click(function(){
        $('#content').html(orginalText);
    });
```

**home.html** code:

```
<a href="#" id="changeText">Click here to change text of div</a>
<a href="#" id="changeText2">Original Div content</a>
<div id="content">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
</div>
```

When I click on link, it says originalText not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change normal function to **[arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)** , and access `orginalText` with `this.orginalText` ,

```
orginalText;

ngOnInit () {
    $('#changeText').click(() => {
        this.orginalText = $('#content').html();
        $('#content').text("This is text changed using jquery");
    });

    $('#changeText2').click(() => {
        $('#content').html(this.orginalText);
    });
}
```

Comment: why do we need this arrow function, can you guide more on this ?

Comment: There is no need of arrow , it's just scope related , With normal function you can't access `this.orginalText` , if you want you can go 2 ways , 1. Arrow Function 2. Bind this , rest you can know from the given link in answer

Comment: Mine pleasure, Happy Coding BTW :)